# Wildfly-jboss compile problem pom.xml group or phase test plugin

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, jboss, wildfly

I attempted to compile Wildfly server 22 beta  but kept getting errors for
`maven-surefire-plugin` and appears to be on its version 2.22.2.
I changed the version to 3.0.0-M5.

```
ERROR Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test)
  on project wildfly-clustering-ee-spi: There are test failures.
```

It then mentioned goal or phase tags in reference to tests

```
ERROR No goals have been specified for this build.
  You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format plugin-prefix:goal 
  or plugin-group-id:plugin-artifact-id[:plugin-version]:goal. 

Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, 
generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, 
process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, 
process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, 
post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, 
site, 
post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]*
```

So I set the test in the plugin config to `test` it was `none`.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test)
  on project wildfly-clustering-ee-spi: There are test failures.
```

This is my Linux Suse shell prompt with regard to the clustering yest report output file:

```
samuel@linux-l7xz:~/JBOSS-Serv-4_0-source/wildfly-22.0.0.Beta1-src/clustering/ee/spi/target/surefire-reports

THE REPORT
org.wildfly.clustering.ee.immutable.DefaultImmutabilityTestCase.txt
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: org.wildfly.clustering.ee.immutable.DefaultImmutabilityTestCase
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.044 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.wildfly.clustering.ee.immutable.DefaultImmutabilityTestCase
org.wildfly.clustering.ee.immutable.DefaultImmutabilityTestCase.test  Time elapsed: 0.038 s  <<< ERROR!
java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-l7xz: linux-l7xz: Name or service not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1506)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.ee.immutable.DefaultImmutabilityTestCase.test(DefaultImmutabilityTestCase.java:115)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.ee.immutable.DefaultImmutabilityTestCase.test(DefaultImmutabilityTestCase.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:364)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:237)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:428)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:562)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:548)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-l7xz: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1501)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: You can compile it with `-DskipTests` if you're just trying to get a build of the server.

Comment: Where does your source come from ?

Comment: Found the problem ****, i'm in opensuse leap and the computer name on the prompt is  linux-l7xz , i changed the computer name to localhost and it went through compile, with downloads 53 minutes , with processed 15 minutes. source from wildfly.org